# asp.net mvc 2 wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

does anyone have a link to some code for a wizard control in asp.net mvc 2? preferable one without using the session ? i would like to persist all the values in between steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework 2nd Edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=lfPkn31fpNQC&pg=PA477#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple component MVCWizard.Wizard available on NuGet. The WizardController allows you to create a wizard using partial view. There is also the AutoWizardController that renders the entire wizard in a single view. All these components operate with the session to store the model state. There are also some examples of the use of these classes on NuGet. These components works on MVC3.