# Does Wizard Control work in ASP.NET MVC 2 MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have dropped a wizard control on the index page of an asp.net mvc 2 project. The button Next and Previous don't work.

Is the wizard control tailored for ASP.NET MVC2 ? If not can it be fixed and how ?

Comment: As a general statement, using ASP.NET server controls in MVC is not recommended because the server controls combine the Controller+View concerns, which should be kept separate.

Comment: The control should be a COMPONENT which behave a single entity, from my app viewpoint it's just a control like button it should have no side effect on my code. So either the ASP.NET model is flawed either the Wizard control is not really a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. I am pretty sure the `WizardControl` relies pretty heavily on `ViewState` which is not in MVC.

I did find this: [asp.net mvc 2 wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228398/asp-net-mvc-2-wizard)

Answer (score 1):

No, the wizard does not work. For simpler wizards -- where you are really just breaking the data entry into pages to make it a bit more platable, we are building single big forms and then using the [jquery formwizard plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard) to break up the flow. Works like a charm and prehaps more capable than the old wizard was.

Comment: Thanks will look at this but would like to first look at server control.

Comment: @user310291: you do understand there is no such thing as a server conrol in MVC. Or anywhere in the world but ASP.NET webforms . . .